# Scrapy : Fetching table tr using css selector is not working

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
<table  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This layout table is used to present the sections found" width="100%"><caption class="captiontext">Sections Found</caption>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddtitle" scope="colgroup" ><a href="/ssbprod/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=202130&amp;crn_in=30571">Introduction to Computers - 30571 - CS 100 - 001</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<TD CLASS="dddefault">
Plus one lab section 081 to 088
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Associated Term: </SPAN>2021 Fall 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Registration Dates: </SPAN>Mar 02, 2021 to Sep 13, 2021 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Levels: </SPAN>Undergraduate 
<br />
<br />
On Campus
<br />
Lecture Schedule Type
<br />
Remote Learning Delivery Spec Instructional Method
<br />
       3.000 Credits
<br />
<a href="/ssbprod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses?term_in=202130&amp;one_subj=CS&amp;sel_crse_strt=100&amp;sel_crse_end=100&amp;sel_subj=&amp;sel_levl=&amp;sel_schd=&amp;sel_coll=&amp;sel_divs=&amp;sel_dept=&amp;sel_attr=">View Catalog Entry</a>
<br />
<br />
<table  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class.."><caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Time</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Where</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Date Range</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Schedule Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Class</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">7:00 pm - 9:45 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">T</td>
<td class="dddefault">Remote</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Aug 30, 2021 - Dec 06, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault"><ABBR title = "To Be Announced">TBA</ABBR></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">7:00 pm - 10:00 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">T</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault"><ABBR title = "To Be Announced">TBA</ABBR></td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Dec 21, 2021 - Dec 21, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Examination</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault"><ABBR title = "To Be Announced">TBA</ABBR></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
</TD>
</tr>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddtitle" scope="colgroup" ><a href="/ssbprod/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=202130&amp;crn_in=33171">Introduction to Computers - 33171 - CS 100 - S01</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<TD CLASS="dddefault">
<B><font color="FF000">Course restricted to FNUniv until July 30. Plus lab section S03-S07.</b></font><BR>
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Associated Term: </SPAN>2021 Fall 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Registration Dates: </SPAN>Mar 02, 2021 to Sep 13, 2021 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Levels: </SPAN>Undergraduate 
<br />
<br />
On Campus
<br />
Lecture Schedule Type
<br />
Remote Learning Delivery Spec Instructional Method
<br />
       3.000 Credits
<br />
<a href="/ssbprod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses?term_in=202130&amp;one_subj=CS&amp;sel_crse_strt=100&amp;sel_crse_end=100&amp;sel_subj=&amp;sel_levl=&amp;sel_schd=&amp;sel_coll=&amp;sel_divs=&amp;sel_dept=&amp;sel_attr=">View Catalog Entry</a>
<br />
<br />
<table  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class.."><caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Time</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Where</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Date Range</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Schedule Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Class</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">1:30 pm - 2:20 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">MWF</td>
<td class="dddefault">Remote</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Aug 30, 2021 - Dec 06, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Richard Wayne  Dosselmann (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)<a href="mailto:dosselmann@hotmail.com"    target="Richard W. Dosselmann" ><img src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" align="middle" alt="E-mail" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="E-mail"  NAME="web_email" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=28 WIDTH=28 /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">2:00 pm - 5:00 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">F</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault"><ABBR title = "To Be Announced">TBA</ABBR></td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Dec 17, 2021 - Dec 17, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Examination</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Richard Wayne  Dosselmann (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)<a href="mailto:dosselmann@hotmail.com"    target="Richard W. Dosselmann" ><img src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" align="middle" alt="E-mail" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="E-mail"  NAME="web_email" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=28 WIDTH=28 /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
</TD>
</tr>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddtitle" scope="colgroup" ><a href="/ssbprod/bwckschd.p_disp_detail_sched?term_in=202130&amp;crn_in=33172">Introduction to Computers - 33172 - CS 100 - S02</a></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<TD CLASS="dddefault">
<B><font color="FF000">PLUS LAB SECTION S03-S07</b></font><BR>
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Associated Term: </SPAN>2021 Fall 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Registration Dates: </SPAN>Mar 02, 2021 to Sep 13, 2021 
<br />
<SPAN class="fieldlabeltext">Levels: </SPAN>Undergraduate 
<br />
<br />
On Campus
<br />
Lecture Schedule Type
<br />
Remote Learning Delivery Spec Instructional Method
<br />
       3.000 Credits
<br />
<a href="/ssbprod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses?term_in=202130&amp;one_subj=CS&amp;sel_crse_strt=100&amp;sel_crse_end=100&amp;sel_subj=&amp;sel_levl=&amp;sel_schd=&amp;sel_coll=&amp;sel_divs=&amp;sel_dept=&amp;sel_attr=">View Catalog Entry</a>
<br />
<br />
<table  CLASS="datadisplaytable" SUMMARY="This table lists the scheduled meeting times and assigned instructors for this class.."><caption class="captiontext">Scheduled Meeting Times</caption>
<tr>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Time</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Days</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Where</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Date Range</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Schedule Type</th>
<th CLASS="ddheader" scope="col" >Instructors</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Class</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">1:30 pm - 2:20 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">MWF</td>
<td class="dddefault">Remote</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Aug 30, 2021 - Dec 06, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Lecture</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Richard Wayne  Dosselmann (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)<a href="mailto:dosselmann@hotmail.com"    target="Richard W. Dosselmann" ><img src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" align="middle" alt="E-mail" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="E-mail"  NAME="web_email" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=28 WIDTH=28 /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td CLASS="dddefault">&nbsp;</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">2:00 pm - 5:00 pm</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">F</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault"><ABBR title = "To Be Announced">TBA</ABBR></td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Dec 17, 2021 - Dec 17, 2021</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Examination</td>
<td CLASS="dddefault">Richard Wayne  Dosselmann (<ABBR title= "Primary">P</ABBR>)<a href="mailto:dosselmann@hotmail.com"    target="Richard W. Dosselmann" ><img src="/wtlgifs/web_email.gif" align="middle" alt="E-mail" CLASS="headerImg" TITLE="E-mail"  NAME="web_email" HSPACE=0 VSPACE=0 BORDER=0 HEIGHT=28 WIDTH=28 /></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />
</TD>
</tr>
</table>
```

I am trying to fetch all tr of the table using for loop but it outputs null.
These are list of courses offered. In table first tr has title of the course and second tr has its course details. And table has no id or name. There can be many courses .

URL for the page : https://banner.uregina.ca:17023/ssbprod/bwckctlg.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=202130&subj_in=CS&crse_in=100&schd_in=A
[image]

Here can be multiple courses listed

My Script:

```
   def parse_courseTimings(self, response):

        sub_courses_tables = response.css('table.datadisplaytable tr')

        flag2 = 0
        for sub_course in sub_courses_tables:
            flag2 = flag2 + 1
       
            if flag2 == 1:
                title = sub_course.css('th.ddttitle a::text').extract_first()
                print(title)
            else:
                text = sub_course.css('td.dddefault :: text').extract()
                # while "\n" in text: text.remove("\n")
                print(text)
            if flag2 == 2:
                flag2 = 0
```

Here, output of title and text is null []. And also getting this error

```
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::table[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' datadisplaytable ')]/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\n<th class="ddtitle" scope="colgr...'>
None
None
<Selector xpath="descendant-or-self::table[@class and contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' datadisplaytable ')]/descendant-or-self::*/tr" data='<tr>\n<td class="dddefault">\nPlus one ...'>
None
2021-03-31 12:34:59 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://banner.uregina.ca:17023/ssbprod/bwckctlg.p_disp_listcrse?term_in=202130&subj_in=CS&crse_in=330&schd_in=A> (referer: https://banner.uregina.ca:17023/s
sbprod/bwckctlg.p_display_courses)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 662, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\UPosia\PycharmProjects\ScheduleScraper\schedule_crawler\schedule_crawler\spiders\schedule_spider.py", line 144, in parse_courseTimings
    text = sub_course.css('td.dddefault :: text').extract()
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 282, in css
    return self.xpath(self._css2xpath(query))
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\selector.py", line 285, in _css2xpath
    return self._csstranslator.css_to_xpath(query)
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\parsel\csstranslator.py", line 107, in css_to_xpath
    return super(HTMLTranslator, self).css_to_xpath(css, prefix)
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\xpath.py", line 192, in css_to_xpath
    for selector in parse(css))
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\parser.py", line 415, in parse
    return list(parse_selector_group(stream))
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\parser.py", line 428, in parse_selector_group
    yield Selector(*parse_selector(stream))
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\parser.py", line 454, in parse_selector
    next_selector, pseudo_element = parse_simple_selector(stream)
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\parser.py", line 503, in parse_simple_selector
    pseudo_element = stream.next_ident()
  File "c:\users\uposia\pycharmprojects\schedulescraper\venv\lib\site-packages\cssselect\parser.py", line 819, in next_ident
    raise SelectorSyntaxError('Expected ident, got %s' % (next,))
  File "<string>", line None
cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected ident, got <S ' ' at 15>
```

I am not sure what is the problem here.
I am trying to fetch all the details of the course content. However, when I was trying to fetch information of each of the courses using for loop. But It raising erro.

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy: When fetching multiple tr from table, output in null \[\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891663/scrapy-when-fetching-multiple-tr-from-table-output-in-null)

Comment: No that is deleted question. I already got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update: this question is solved I just had to add summary attribute to table while fetching the tr.

```
sub_courses_tables = response.css('table.datadisplaytable tr')
#correct code

sub_courses_tables = response.css('table.datadisplaytable[summary="This layout table is used to present the sections found"] tr')
```

Comment: Yes, This corrected evrything. Actually the issue was that in page's HTML the table I was scraping had another table inside it with same name attribute the only thing that make the first table unique is the summary attriute. @QHarr